# Pointer to function returning matrix of struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers, typedef

I'm trying to create typedef to  function pointer which returns matrix of struct.
I tried:

```
typedef struct my_struct**  (*func)(void)
typedef struct my_struct[4][4] (*func)(void)
```

but none of them worked.
My matrix of struct is initialized like:

```
static struct my_struct matrix[4][4];
```

my code didn't compiled with the 2 options of typedef.
How should I create this typedef?
Thanks.

Comment: What are the compilation errors?

Comment: Expected ) before [ (or something like that)

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your first `typedef` and nothing which can point to one. A pointer is not an array! And you cannot pass arrays to/from functions.

Comment: You cannot return an array from a function, so 2 is flat out. You can return a pointer from a function, but your pointer is of the wrong type, so 1 also fails. I suggest wrapping your `matrix` in yet another struct to avoid dealing with pointers.

Comment: @n.m.: Why not return a `whatever (*)[4]`?

Comment: @Olaf because you need to care about the lifetime of whatever it points to.

Comment: @n.m.: So what?

Comment: I don't want to create struct with only matrix in it .. it's not good coding in my opinion .. another suggestion please?

Comment: @Olaf Do you volunteer to take care of bugs that will result from OP not understanding pointers? I don't.

Comment: @n.m.: OP already does not understand arrays and pointers. Recommending the correct approach does not do any harm, but might lead him to do research. You cannot use arrays without dealing with pointers anyway.

Comment: @Rotemben Show me some good programming then.

Comment: @n.m. if I had one I wouldn't ask ..

Comment: @Rotemben So perhaps your opinion about what is good programming and what is not might potentially be not quite well founded. Have you considered this possibility?

Comment: @Olaf A programmer doesn't have to know or care much about pointers in order to use fixed-size arrays. You cannot use arrays *fully* without dealing with pointers, but as they say, one cow at a time.

Comment: @n.m.: This is about C and this language is special about pointers and arrays. Every access and every time you pass an array to/from a function uses a pointer and you should never forget about this fact. At least if you want to be a good C programmer. And your recommendation is not good programming. Just wrapping something into a `struct` because you don't know how to declare it does not make "wrapping a wrapper into a wrapper" good coding style **in C**!

Comment: @Olaf "you should never forget about this fact" I hold an opposite point of view. Every time you *can* forget about something, you *should*. That's called abstraction. "you don't know how to declare it" No, that's not the reason to wrap an array in a struct. The reason is the desire to pass it by value like any other C object.

Comment: @n.m.: C does not provide an abstraction for pointers! They are first class types! Try `int a[100], *p = a; sizeof(p) == sizeof(a);` You might confuse them with C++ references.

Comment: @Olaf I don't want to deal with pointers, why should I try anything about `p`? I just want `a` thank you very much. For what most people do most of the time, array-to-pointer decay just doesn't matter. They just need to remember a few arcane things: don't return an array, don't try to `sizeof` an array parameter, and arrays are magically passed by reference. Are you saying array decay is easier to understand? Go ahead and explain it to the crowd...

Comment: @n.m.: I talked about a **good** programmer. The rest will continue posting faulting code with `sizeof(array_parameter)` issues. Telling beginners they should not care about this is the opposite of helpful. My students did not have problems understanding this. And my mother will not even get that far.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be returned. You can however return a pointer to an array. This is what should be returned if you want to retrieve your 2d array from a function.

The function would return a pointer to an array of 4 structs:

```
struct my_struct (*function(void))[4];
```

typedef of this type:

```
typedef struct my_struct (*type(void))[4];
type* p = function;
```

Comment: Also, if you want copy semantics you can return a `struct` that contains an array.

Comment: If I understood, in case of struct my_struct matrix[2][4]..I need to write typedef struct my_struct (*type(void))[2] ? Which return pointer to array of 4 struct?

Comment: @Rotemben In that case the definition wouldn't change. What this function returns is a pointer to an array of 4 structs. `struct my_struct matrix[2][4].` defines an array of two arrays of 4 structs.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be returned from functions.

One can return a pointer to the first element of an array. In your case, the first element of your array is itself an array (a row in a matrix). The syntax needed to declare a pointer to a function returning a pointer to an array is too arcane to be used directly. The most simple, user-friendly way to deal with the situation is to use a typedef .

```
typedef struct my_struct row[4];  // a 4-element row in a matrix
typedef row* (*func)(void);       // pointer-to-function returning pointer-to-row
```

You *cannot* omit the size and *cannot* use a pointer instead of an array, i.e.

```
typedef struct my_struct row[];
typedef row* (*func)(void);    // doesn't do what you want

typedef struct my_struct *row;
typedef row* (*func)(void);    // doesn't do what you want
```

You have to know that returning a pointer into a *local* array is not allowed in C.

```
row* myfunc(void)
{
   struct my_struct my_matrix[4][4];
   return my_matrix; // will compile, but the behaviour is undefined
                     // a good compiler will warn you
}
```

You can return a pointer to a static object or to a dynamically allocated object this way.

If you want to return objects and not pointers, you have to use a wrapper struct.

```
typedef struct { struct my_struct elements[4][4]; } wrapper;

wrapper (*foo)(void); //OK
wrapper myfunc(void) 
{
   wrapper w;
   return w; // OK
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand: typedef struct matrix row[4];  // a 4-element row in a matrix ... Do you mean typedef struct my_struct matrix[2][4] row[4]?

Comment: @Rotemben I have changed the identifiers to match yours. Hope it is more clear now.